# Why difference in localhost vs 127.0.0.1 regarding SESSIONS

Tags: php, session, localhost

I'm wondering why there's a difference in these two for sessions? If i have a login form and it passes sessions to a page (ie: `settings.php`). If i have `localhost/settings.php` the session would work, if I go to a different page and come back. but if it is `127.0.0.1/settings.php`, the session will work on the first pass, then if I redirect somewhere else and go back, its not there anymore.

Does this happen to other people too? Or is this just me?

Thanks

Comment: Session... is a cookie on a client side, nope? I may be wrong, but i suppose that cookie is strictly mapped to the domain name and is not sent to 127.0.0.1 by browser because cookie domain is localhost. I mean that it looks like crossdomain request from browser's view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this will help:
http://www.issociate.de/board/post/179979/Cookie_Problems_on_Localhost.html

> both 'localhost' and any ip are not accepted as valid
>   domain-identifiers  in cookies (as per RFC).

and 127.0.0.1 != localhost for browser. browser will not send cookie that was set from 127.0.0.1 to localhost, because they are different domains.

p.s. in practice, there can be many domains on one ip. and for security reasons, of course, browser can't send all cookies altogether (imagine, that cookies from your website could be sent by browser to all websites on virtualhosting with the same ip).

Answer (score 3):

Due to the problems referenced in @true's answer, in our development we usually create a fake local domain like dev.localhost.net and use the hosts file to map this either to the machine ip address or to 127.0.0.1. This helps get around the session/cookie problem.

Comment: This works great for devs, but doesn't work well for UI automation testers.  Modifying the hosts file is usually not an option on CI/CD pipeline boxes shared by multiple teams.  The best workaround I've found is to place an embedded (as in: launched by and controlled from the tests themselves) proxy server between the browser and the actual test environment.  The proxy can then be configured to redirect HTTP requests for dev.localhost.net to 127.0.0.1 internally without involving the hosts file.