# Why does my Julia server on localhost hang?

Tags: http, get, julia

I'm trying to start a simple server in Julia. (Julia 1.7, HTTP v0.9.16, Windows 10).

By copying the snippet in the HTTP docs, I've written

```
using HTTP
using Sockets
HTTP.serve(Sockets.localhost, 8000) do request::HTTP.Request 
    @show HTTP.header(request, "Content-Type")
    @show HTTP.payload(request)
    return HTTP.Response("Helllllo")
end
```

in a julia terminal.

When i navigate to `http://localhost:8000/` in Chrome, it Does show a page with the word "Helllllo".

But, when i try to send GET requests to it, it doesn't answer. Things I tried:

- Opening a new julia terminal and writing

  ```
   using HTTP
   r = HTTP.request("GET", "https://127.0.0.1:8000");
  ```

What happens is that this command hangs, instead of producing a `r`.

- Going in Chrome console and writing

  ```
   fetch("https://127.0.0.1:8000")
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(console.log)
  ```

Again, no answer.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple different issues:

1. You're trying to read from a `https` address, after having set up a plain `http` server. Once you fix this, Julia is able to get a request-response:

```
julia> r = HTTP.request("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8000")
HTTP.Messages.Response:
"""
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Helllllo"""
```

2. But it still fails in the browser (in Firefox - I assume it will be the same in Chrome) with

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8000/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

This is simply because [127.0.0.1 != localhost for browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10663798/8127), [for security purposes](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/173760/29536) (so it doesn't allow you to read from the "different" host at `127.0.0.1` while you're on `localhost`). If you instead do:

```
>> fetch("http://localhost:8000")
   .then(console.log)

Promise { <state>: "pending" }

Response { type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:8000/", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }
```